# setters and getters for enum class inside other class

Tags: c++, enums, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I have base class `Employee` and derived class `concreteEmployee`.

```
class Employee {
    virtual void &getStatus() {}  ??
}

class concreteEmployee : public Employee {

public:
enum class Status {
    Intern,
    Worker,
    Manager
};

Status status;

void setStatus() {
    ?????
}


... &getStatus() { // virtual from Employee
    return Status; ???
}
```

My vector of pointers is `vector<shared_ptr<Employee>> Firm;` and I'm passing by reference `sourceEmployee`.
What I'm trying to do is:

1. set concrete status while hiring new employee like "`Worker`".

   ```
   void hireEmployee(vector<shared_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {
   sourceEmployee.emplace_back(new concreteEmployee(fillName, fillSurname));
   sourceEmployee.back()->status = ???
   ```

   I want to do it that way instead of using `std::string Status = "Worker"` field in `concreteEmployee` etc.
   and classic setter/getter.
2. I want to get the status of `concreteEmployee` from `Employee` class and print it somewhere. I have vector of derived objects (using `std::shared_ptr`) and want to get the status like this maybe?

   ```
   void employeeShowcase(const vector<shared_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {
       cout << sourceEmployee[index]->getStatus()
       ... // output should be like i.e "Worker"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Employee status should be visible to consumers of your class then that implies you must define that enum in the scope of `Employee`, not `ConcreteEmployee`